# Why hadoop just stuck there after I set the map compression properties?

Tags: java, hadoop

Here's the code snippet that works fine:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();

//PROBLEM PART!!!!!
//conf.setBoolean("mapred.compress.map.output", true);
//conf.set("mapred.output.compression.type", "BLOCK");
//conf.setClass("mapred.map.output.compression.codec", GzipCodec.class, CompressionCodec.class);

Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");
job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

job.setMapperClass(WordCountMap.class);
job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

But if I enable the **PROBLEM PART** in the code snippet above, the output of console will stuck at:

```
13/12/26 18:08:06 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
13/12/26 18:08:06 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
13/12/26 18:08:06 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
13/12/26 18:08:06 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 20
13/12/26 18:08:06 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
13/12/26 18:08:06 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local1943436108_0001
13/12/26 18:08:06 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
13/12/26 18:08:06 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local1943436108_0001_m_000000_0
13/12/26 18:08:07 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
13/12/26 18:08:07 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@731d2572
13/12/26 18:08:07 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: hdfs://localhost:9000/user/jude/input/capacity-scheduler.xml:0+7457
13/12/26 18:08:07 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
13/12/26 18:08:07 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
13/12/26 18:08:07 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
13/12/26 18:08:07 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/12/26 18:08:07 INFO compress.CodecPool: Got brand-new compressor
13/12/26 18:08:07 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
13/12/26 18:08:07 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/12/26 18:08:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
13/12/26 18:08:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 5% reduce 0%
//no more
```

I just intend to compress the output of map, is there anything wrong with my code? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using compression requires Hadoop to use native libraries for your platform, but apparently you don't have them (or have not configured the path to the libraries correctly). This is the message that is explaining the problem:

```
[...] NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform...
```

Possible solutions:

- Most common problem is to have the 32-bit libraries on a 64-bit architecture. You can download the [pre-compiled 64 native libraries OR compile them yourself using `mvn package -Pdist,**native**,docs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18604720/trouble-with-64bit-linux-native-library-for-hadoop-2-1-beta).
- Or, you may need to configure the path to the native libraries correctly; see these other questions on how to do this: [use -Djava.libray.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19966790/failure-to-load-the-native-hadoop-library), or [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10878038/warn-snappy-loadsnappy-snappy-native-library-not-loaded).

Comment: Thanks, as you said, I fogot to add the `java.libray.path` property in eclipse :)